# Java Reflection - Get List of Packages

Tags: java, reflection

I am building a Java app that has a number of different packages. I want to be able to tell programmatically which packages exist in the app that start with a specific pre-fix.  Is there anyway to do this with the Java reflection APIs?  I didn't see anything like this related to the reflection apis.

Example:

```
com.app.controls.text
com.app.controls.picker
com.app.controls.date
etc
```

I want to enumerate all of these by knowing the prefix "com.app.controls" and understanding that a new package might get integrated in the future.

Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can do this by using [Package.getPackages()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Package.html#getPackages%28%29), which returns an array of all packages known to the current class loader. You'll have to manually loop through the array and find the ones with the appropriate prefix using [getName()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Package.html#getName%28%29).

Here's a quick example:

```
public List<String> findPackageNamesStartingWith(String prefix) {
    return Package.getPackages().stream()
        .map(Package::getName)
        .filter(n -> n.startsWith(prefix))
        .collect(toList());
}
```

Note that this technique will only return the packages defined in the current class loader. If you need the packages from a different class loader, there are some options:

1. Arrange things so that your program can run the above code from inside that class loader. This requires a certain organisation to your code base, which may or may not be feasible.
2. Use reflection to call the (normally protected) method [getPackages()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getPackages%28%29) on the appropriate class loader. This won't work if the program is running under a security manager.

Comment: Unfortunately the packages aren't known to the current class loader.  Is there any other possible way?

Comment: Probably not, other than listing them explicitly.

Comment: @DerekGebhard: Two possibilities came to mind. I've added them to the answer.

Comment: `Package.getPackages()` returns an array. You need to use `Arrays.stream(Package.getPackages())` instead of `Package.getPackages().stream()`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Sean's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13944677/853744) and using reflection to get a list of packages - possibly ignoring empty ones:

```
/**
 * Finds all package names starting with prefix
 * @return Set of package names
 */
public Set<String> findAllPackagesStartingWith(String prefix) {
    List<ClassLoader> classLoadersList = new LinkedList<ClassLoader>();
    classLoadersList.add(ClasspathHelper.contextClassLoader());
    classLoadersList.add(ClasspathHelper.staticClassLoader());
    Reflections reflections = new Reflections(new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .setScanners(new SubTypesScanner(false), new ResourcesScanner())
            .setUrls(ClasspathHelper.forClassLoader(classLoadersList.toArray(new ClassLoader[0])))
            .filterInputsBy(new FilterBuilder().include(FilterBuilder.prefix("my.base.package"))));
    Set<Class<? extends Object>> classes = reflections.getSubTypesOf(Object.class);

    Set<String> packageNameSet = new TreeSet<String>();
    for (Class classInstance : classes) {
        String packageName = classInstance.getPackage().getName();
        if (packageName.startsWith(prefix)) {
            packageNameSet.add(packageName);
        }
    }
    return packageNameSet;
}
```

Comment: Most of these classes don't exist in my native library. Are you using a third party?

Comment: @LordFarquaad this is an old response (January, 2014) I assume your Java version is fairly new compared to what I was using back then.